# How to get one container from another by localhost?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am newby to the docker world.
I can't wrap my head for a while on docker networks in general and how to properly connect my backend and frontend inside of a docker-compose file in particular. I want these both services to communicate with each other by localhost:port, not with services name. I know it's related to the networks, but don't know how to use it the way I want. Thank you!

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.11'

services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${PGDATABASE}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${PGUSER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - static_volume:/app/backend/static
      - media_volume:/app/backend/media
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - IS_DOCKER=true
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node_modules:/app/frontend/node_modules
      - static_volume:/app/frontend/public/static
    depends_on:
      - db
      - backend

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    working_dir: /app
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/frontend/public/static
      - media_volume:/app/backend/media
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend

volumes:
  pg_data:
  node_modules:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two containers **cannot** communicate using `localhost`[*], because `localhost` means "this container". If you want your `frontend` container to access the `backend` container, it should use the hostname `backend`...and if you want the `backend` container to access the `db` container, it should use the hostname `db` (etc...).

---

* You can actually configure a container to run in the same [network namespace](https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/) as another container by setting the [`network_mode`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode) option to `service:<server_name>`, but in general you don't need to do that.

Comment: Thank you for a reply and several articles, I'll read it to become more friendly with docker! I knew about how to connect frontend and backend using service name, but it fires some errors later on, in production. For example, my DRF backend returns an absolute url with backend:8000 that for sure can't be reached on the client. CORS issue existing as well. But as far as I investigate this question more and more, I am starting to understand that nginx and reverse proxy feature of it will heal CORS issue. Using relative path on the backend will fix other one problem.